# iOS7 UISearchBar not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm trying to put a searchbar inside a TableView which is a subview of a simple ViewController. The result compiled it's this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3v57.png)

Now everything works and I can search correctly. The problem is the visual glitch I had when I search something: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEMth.png)

What I want it's just that the search bar goes to the top of the screen or better that my header don't disappear.

Comment: header is a UITableView's Header or custom header?

Comment: I've placed a TableView inside a ViewController like this: [Screen](http://i.imgur.com/we4h7rl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame of the searchBar with animation just to the top of the screen when search bar start begin editing (when keyboard appears). just like that-

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
CGRect frame=searchBar.frame;
frame.origin.y=0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    searchBar.frame=frame;
}];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to place this inside the method **shouldReloadTableForSearchString** ?

Comment: No, rather in UISearchBar delegate method-

– searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:

which called when user taps in the search bar.

Comment: The bar just don't move from his position. I've tried with the following code:
`- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"beginEditing");
    CGRect frame = searchBar.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 animations:^{
        searchBar.frame=frame;
    }];
}`

Comment: sorry, replace the origin.x with origin.y

Comment: I'm sorry but with your code nothing change. Same issue as before.

Comment: what is the frame of your search bar?

Comment: check that your searchBarTextDidBeginEditing is being called or not.

Comment: It's called once (that's why I put a NSLog inside) when i tap the searchbar.

Comment: i just tried that and my search bar going up when i tap.

Comment: Are you using a TableViewController or a TableView inside a ViewController like me? I think that's the problem.

Comment: use tableView inside a viewController, this would be better approach.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the searchbar it's inside the tableview! Maibe thats the problem. I need inside because i wan't to hide it on scroll..

Comment: this is not the right way to do so. you can not do much editing with tableviewcontroller

Comment: Can you help me to develop in the right way? What can i do? Thank you so much for the help.